# Using reprepro to build raspberry pi OS image

Tags: raspberry-pi, operating-system

We are building customized Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 OS using pi-gen.  pi-gen always pulls the latest packages from raspbian.raspberrypi.com repository each time it is executed.  As we near release, we would like to freeze the package versions to maintain consistent and trackable software version we deliver.  We would want to be able to selectively update packages as needed until the next major software release.  reprepro looks to be able to do what we want, but it is unclear to me how to set it up.

pi-gen uses specialized scripts to build the OS image.  Very early on, it sets up APT sources.list to point to the apt repository and later scripts install packages from there.  We add extra post-processing scripts to tailor the final image to our needs, adding and removing files to create the minimum sized image for our product.  Our goal is to not alter any of the pi-gen files, only add to them.

Here is what I would like to do:

1. Take a snapshot of all the packages loaded in the image and load them into reprepro.
2. Externally redirect all access to raspbian.raspberrypi.com to the local reprepro.
3. If a package is not present in reprepro, automatically load it from the original URL and use the local copy going forward.

Item 3 is not needed but would be a nice feature so the long build doesn't fail and have to be restarted.

Is the above possible?  And how do I set it up?